# Get latest build artifact from nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, repository, artifacts

i'm using Jenkins and nexus . after release my artifact i store that in nexus artifact repository, and i deploy that artifact using Jenkins while building. now my requirement is change deployment life cycle. i want store artifact to the nexus repository after build from maven(this part already done). than i want to get latest release artifact from nexus repository and deploy that artifact.can i do this using Jenkins ? if not what is the best way.

Current i do,

- build using Jenkins
- store build artifact to the nexus repository.
- deploy artifact.

what i want ,

- build using Jenkins.
- store build artifact to the nexus repository.
- get latest artifact from nexus repository.
- deploy latest artifact (fetched previous step).

Answer (score 0):

use Jenkins [Repository Connector](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Repository+Connector+Plugin) Artifact Resolver Build Step